# Image Rotation in a C++ Method

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, image-rotation

I had posted before on Stack Overflow for the question how exactly to rotate a BMP image in a c++ program. Now, however, I have more to show in regards of my progress.

I was wondering how (or why) my program will not output the image after I do the image calculation:

```
void BMPImage::Rotate45Left(float point1, float point2, float point3)
{
  float radians = (2 * 3.1416*45) / 360;

  float cosine = (float)cos(radians);
  float sine = (float)sin(radians);

  float point1Xtreme = 0;
  float point1Yearly = 0;
  float point2Xtreme = 0;
  float point2Yearly = 0;
  float point3Xtreme = 0;
  float point3Yearly = 0;

int SourceBitmapHeight = m_BIH.biHeight;
int SourceBitmapWidth = m_BIH.biWidth;

point1Xtreme = (-m_BIH.biHeight*sine);
point1Yearly = (m_BIH.biHeight*cosine);
point2Xtreme = (m_BIH.biWidth*cosine - m_BIH.biHeight*sine);
point2Yearly = (m_BIH.biHeight*cosine + m_BIH.biWidth*sine);
point3Xtreme = (m_BIH.biWidth*cosine);
point3Yearly = (m_BIH.biWidth*sine);

float Minx = min(0, min(point1Xtreme, min(point2Xtreme, point3Xtreme)));
float Miny = min(0, min(point1Yearly, min(point2Yearly, point3Yearly)));
float Maxx = max(point1Xtreme, max(point2Xtreme, point3Xtreme));
float Maxy = max(point1Yearly, max(point2Yearly, point3Yearly));

int FinalBitmapWidth = (int)ceil(fabs(Maxx) - Minx);
int FinalBitmapHeight = (int)ceil(fabs(Maxy) - Miny);
FinalBitmapHeight = m_BIH.biHeight;
FinalBitmapWidth = m_BIH.biWidth;
int finalBitmap;
```

If anyone has any helpful pointers, that would be great.
I should mention that:

- I can't use other outside libraries for the purpose of this program
- It is a small image processing program, which has a menu system

Comment: Your code does not seem to be doing any rotation at all so no image output would be the expected result.

Comment: BTW, my point of posting the above is at SO we are not here to do your homework for you. We can help if you post real code that attempts to solve the problem but does not work as you expect. The code you posted does not even begin to rotate the image. There isn't even an image to rotate..

Answer (score 1):

Image transformation is usually done by projecting a target pixel onto a source pixel then calculating the value for that target pixel. This way you can easily incorporate different interpolation methods.

```
template <typename T>
struct Image {
    Image(T* data, size_t rows, size_t cols) : 
        data_(data), rows_(rows), cols_(cols) {}
    T* data_;
    size_t rows_;
    size_t cols_;
    T& operator()(size_t row, size_t col) {
        return data_[col + row * cols_];
    }
 };

template <typename T>
T clamp(T value, T lower_bound, T upper_bound) {
    value = std::min(std::max(value, lower_bound), upper_bound);
}

void rotate_image(Image const &src, Image &dst, float ang) {
    // Affine transformation matrix 
    // H = [a, b, c]
    //     [d, e, f]

    // Remember, we are transforming from destination to source, 
    // thus the negated angle. 
    float H[] = {cos(-ang), -sin(-ang), dst.cols_/2 - src.cols_*cos(-ang)/2,
                 sin(-ang),  cos(-ang), dst.rows_/2 - src.rows_*cos(-ang)/2}; 


    for (size_t row = 0; row < dst.rows_; ++row) {
       for (size_t col = 0; col < dst.cols_; ++cols) {
           int src_col = round(H[0] * col + H[1] * row + H[2]);
           src_col = clamp(src_col, 0, src.cols_ - 1);
           int src_row = round(H[3] * col + H[4] * row + H[5]);
           src_row = clamp(src_row, 0, src.rows_ - 1);               

           dst(row, col) = src(src_row, src_col);
       }
    }
}
```

The above method rotates an image with an arbitrary angle and uses nearest-neighbour interpolation. I typed it directly into stackoverflow, so it is full of bugs; nonetheless, the concept is there.